# WP Query loop - children in date order

Tags: php, loops, categories, wordpress

I have a WP query loop

```
foreach($children as $child) :
                $f++;
                $cat = get_category($child);
                $content .= '<li><a href="' . get_category_link($cat->term_id) . '" class="category-child">' . getVariableText($cat->name,40) . ' (' . $cat->count . ')</a></li>';
    endforeach;
```

Produces:

**News**

- March 2014
- April 2014
- May 2014

This outputs 3x child categories under the parent category name, but I wish to order them by **date**, **newest** at the top. Altering the main query doesn't have an effect on the children...any suggestions?

The initial, main query is here, which lists all the parents in A-Z:

```
$category = get_category_by_slug( 'information-index' );

$args = array(
    'type'                     => 'post',
    'parent'                   => $category->term_id,
    'orderby'                  => 'date',
    'order'                    => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'               => 0,

);

$child_categories = get_categories($args);
    $category_list = array();
    $category_list[] = $category->term_id;
    $content = ''; '
```

Is this even possible, as the 'outer' loop is listing categories in **Alphabetical** order?

Any help appreciated. Martin.

Comment: They're category names...not dates. Which means they have no "time" associated with them.

Comment: You may be able to use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert them into usable times.

Comment: Thanks - yes that's right. These are just names of categories. Good point.
So what is the default sort order for children? Number of posts within?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, as @rnevius said these are just category names. strtotime() can be used to convert them to usable times. Thanks all.